# How to print related lines in c++?

Tags: c++

In my code, I want to have a function called *search* that goes through each line in a .txt file and prints out the line if the first number in the sentence contains the number given by the user. For example:

Format of the .txt file:

Each word is separated by a space.

```
17 35 "door"
40 19 "wall"
17 34 "car"
3  9  "window"
```

Output:

```
Enter a desired number:17
17 35 "door"
17 34 "car"
```

How would I go about doing this? In java, I would normally use the .split() function to split the sentence into a list then see if the first index matches the desired input, but I can't find how to do this, and what I can find, I don't understand. My attempts are listed below, but if you have better methods, please list them...I'm still learning. My attempt are located under the search function below:

```
#include<iostream> 
using std::cerr;
using std::endl;
#include <list>
using namespace std; 
#include <fstream>
using std::ofstream;
#include <cstdlib> // for exit function
#include <sstream>
using namespace std;

class Item{

//Access specifer
public: //todo, private with get/set 
string item;
int meshNum;
int mNum;

//constructor 
public:
Item( string item,int mNum, int meshNum  ){
    this->item=item;
    this-> mNum= mNum;
    this-> meshNum= meshNum;
    
}

//Memeber functions
public: 
string getItem(){
    return item;
}
void setItem(string item){
    this->item = item;
}
int getMeshNum(){
    return this->meshNum;
}
void setMeshNum(int meshNum){
    this->meshNum= meshNum;
}

int getMNum(){
    return this->mNum;
}
void setMNum(int mNum){
    this-> mNum= mNum;
}

};
//____________________________________________

 class materialList{
// Access specifer
private: 
list <Item> items;
 
 //constructor 
 public:
/* materialList(){
     this->items = new list<Item>;
} */

 // Memeber fucntions
 public:
 void add(Item &item)
 {
     items.push_back(item);
 }
//print my list
void Print()
 {
     ofstream outdata; // outdata is like cin
     outdata.open("example2.dat"); // opens the file
   if( !outdata ) { // file couldn't be opened
      cerr << "Error: file could not be opened" << endl;
      exit(1);
   }

    for (auto &i : items)
         outdata  << i.getItem() << " "<<i.getMeshNum()<< " "<<i.getMNum()<<endl;  
      
    outdata.close();
 
   
}
void search(ifstream& inFile){ //this function is where I need help on =<
    string line,word;
    int materialNum;
    istringstream iss;
    cout<< "Enter a material number:";
    cin>>materialNum;
    int**arr= (int**)malloc(20*sizeof(int*));
    int i=0;

    while(!inFile.eof()){
        // read line by line from the file
        getline(inFile,line); 
        if(inFile.good()){
            // read word by word in line and place words in arr
            iss.clear(); // clear out state
            iss.str(line);
            iss>> word;
            arr[i]=word;
            
         }
            if (word==cin){
             cout>>line; 
          }
         
        }
    }
    
};
    






 int main(){
     bool value = true;
     string objectName;
     int Mnum;
     int Meshnum;
     materialList ml; //(list<Item> test);
     while(value){
         cout<< "Enter Object name: ";
         cin>> objectName;
         cout<<" Enter M#: ";
         cin>> Mnum;
         cout<<"Enter Mesh#: ";
         cin>> Meshnum;
         //Item second= Item(objectName,Mnum,Meshnum);
         ml.add(Item(objectName,Mnum,Meshnum));
         ml.Print();

     }
     
     
     //Item test= Item("door",34,50);
     //itemList = 
     
     //ml.add(test);
     //ml.Print();

 }
```

Errors:

```
material_characterizationf.cpp:105:20: error: assigning to 'int *' from incompatible type 'std::__1::string' (aka 'basic_string<char, char_traits<char>, allocator<char> >')
            arr[i]=word;
                   ^~~~
material_characterizationf.cpp:134:17: error: non-const lvalue reference to type 'Item' cannot bind to a temporary of type 'Item'
         ml.add(Item(objectName,Mnum,Meshnum));
                ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

I know the first error comes from my failed attempts, but I have no idea where the second error came from. The code was working fine until I tried to add a *search* function.

Comment: `arr` is an array of `int` pointers.  You cannot assign a `std::string` to one of these elements.  Why are you using `malloc` at all in a C++ program, anyway?  If you want to store strings in a dynamically-allocated array, use `std::vector<std::string>`.

Comment: Regarding the second error, the compiler is telling you that you cannot have a reference to a temporary value unless that value is `const`.  The correct thing to do here is use `const Item&` as the type for that function's parameter.

Comment: @paddy Are vectors normally dynamically allocated?

Comment: @paddy Also, what does the '&' behind Item do?

Comment: @paddy I'm still not understanding... what does that look like in my current header:
 void add(Item &item)

Comment: `void add(const Item& item)`.  Regarding what `&` does, it's a _reference_.  If you are using it without understanding what it is, then it's time to read some learning material on C++.

Answer (score 2):

In your `search` function, I don't think you need to use the `arr` array as not only does it cause memory leak due to it not being freed at the end of the function but also it doesn't serve any purposes in the function. You can simply parse the first argument of the input lines from the file as `int` type into the `word` variable by setting the `word` variable as `int` type instead of `string`.

That way you can use `word` to check if it is equal to the `materialNum` (not equal to `cin` in your original code as it is an `istream` object and can't be compared with an integer) input by the user at line (`cin >> materialNum;`). If `word` is equal to `materialNum`, then you can print out the file line using `out << line << ends;`.

```
void search(ifstream& inFile){
  string line;
  int word;
  int materialNum;
  istringstream iss;
  cout << "Enter a material number:";
  cin >> materialNum;
  int i=0;

  while(!inFile.eof()){
    // read line by line from the file
    getline(inFile,line);
    if(inFile.good()){
      // read word by word in line and place words in arr
      iss.clear(); // clear out state
      iss.str(line);
      iss >> word;
    }

    if (word == materialNum){
      cout << line << endl;
    }

  }
}
```

Update: If you know the file name, you can create a `ifstream` object (`inFile`) to open it, and then pass it as an argument to your `search` function. For example, you can do something like this in your `main` function

```
string filename = "example2.dat";
ifstream inFile;
inFile.open(filename, std::ifstream::in);
ml.search(inFile);
```

Comment: Just one quick question... how do I include the file I want as a parameter in my main() function. Would it be something like this:
`ifstream& inFile;
     inFile= "example2.dat";
     ml.search("example2.dat");`
I'm a bit confused on how to specify the file I want to search.

Comment: @greg Ok I've updated my answer on how to create and pass `inFile` to your `search` function